# Understanding & making infinite bullets to shoot in Pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm learning python and also pygame, and I want to know why the bullets doesn't display, I tough that maybe the `screen.update_screen()` can be interfering but no, that's not the case, I need help to undertand how Bullets work in python because clearly my method is not working, I've seen many methods in other posts, and they use a limited ammount of bullets to shoot (don't know why, in my case I want infinite bullets) so what should I add to see the Bullets, I know that I need to add a remover for seing a "movement" in the display, but I don't know how, any help is appreciated.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pygame

class Screen(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        pygame.display.set_caption("Space Game")
        self.screen_width = 800
        self.screen_heigh = 600
        self.picture = pygame.image.load("screen.png")
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.screen_width, self.screen_heigh))

    def update_screen(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.picture, (0, 0))

    def update_obj(self, object):
        self.screen.blit(object.picture, object.rect)

    def update_shoot(self, object):
        for y in range(object.rect.centery, 600, 10):
            self.screen.blit(object.picture, (object.rect.centerx, object.rect.centery + y))

class Ship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.picture = pygame.image.load("ship.png")
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 400
        self.rect.centery = 500

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, object):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.picture = pygame.image.load("shoot.png")
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = object.rect.centerx
        self.rect.centery = (object.rect.centery + 25)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    done = False
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = Screen()
    ship = Ship()
    bullet = Bullet(ship)

    while not done:
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            ship.rect.centerx -= 5
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            ship.rect.centerx += 5
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            ship.rect.centery -= 5
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            ship.rect.centery += 5

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    done = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    print ("shoot")
                    #for some weird reason the bullet doesn't display
                    screen.update_shoot(bullet)

        screen.update_screen()
        screen.update_obj(ship)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(10)

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To shoot bullets you usually create instances of a `Bullet` class and add them to a list, pygame.sprite.Group or another container. Then you iterate over this container and call the `update` method of the bullet in which its position is changed. To blit the images of the sprites/objects you iterate again over the container and just blit the images onto the screen. With sprite groups you can just call `sprite_group.update()` and `sprite_group.draw(screen)` instead of iterating yourself. BTW, pygame sprites have to have a `self.image` attribute not a `self.picture` in order to work with sprite groups (take a look at [Program Arcade Games](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=de#section_13) for more information).

I started to modify a few things in your example to show you how to use sprite groups, but then ended up changing your whole `Screen` class into a `Game` class (which I recommend to use in the future).

```
import sys
import pygame


class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.done = False
        self.screen_width = 800
        self.screen_height = 600
        self.image = pygame.Surface((800, 600))
        self.image.fill((30, 40, 50))
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.screen_width, self.screen_height))

        # all_sprites is used to update and draw all sprites together.
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        # You'll probably need a separate bullet_group
        # later for collision detection with enemies.
        self.bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self.ship = Ship()
        self.all_sprites.add(self.ship)

        bullet = Bullet(self.ship)
        self.bullet_group.add(bullet)
        self.all_sprites.add(bullet)

    def handle_events(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.ship.rect.centerx -= 5
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.ship.rect.centerx += 5
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.ship.rect.centery -= 5
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.ship.rect.centery += 5

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.done = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    bullet = Bullet(self.ship)
                    self.bullet_group.add(bullet)
                    self.all_sprites.add(bullet)

    def update(self):
        # Calls `update` methods of all contained sprites.
        self.all_sprites.update()

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, (0, 0))
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)  # Draw the contained sprites.
        pygame.display.update()


class Ship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 30))
        self.image.fill((50, 170, 230))
        # A nicer way to set the start pos with `get_rect`.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(400, 500))


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, ship):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((7, 7))
        self.image.fill((230, 140, 30))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.centery = ship.rect.centery - 25

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y -= 5  # Move up 5 pixels per frame.


def main():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption('Space Game')
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    game = Game()

    while not game.done:
        game.handle_events()
        game.update()
        game.draw()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: dude you are a life savior

Comment: My pleasure! You still need to add code to remove the bullets when they leave the screen, otherwise you'll run out of memory ... eventually. ;) Just check if their `rect.y < 0` and then call `self.kill()` to kill the sprite.